# Incorrect file format to parse JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, file, format

My file contains number of JSON records as follows:

Input file:

```
{"timestamp":1487271527,"user":"Dave","action":"browse"}
{"timestamp":1487271528,"user":"Dave","action":"navigate"}
{"timestamp":1487271529,"user":"Dave","action":"browse"}
{"timestamp":1487271530,"user":"Dave","action":"view"}
{"timestamp":1487271531,"user":"Dave","action":"browse"}
{"timestamp":1487271532,"user":"Dave","action":"browse"}
{"timestamp":1487271533,"user":"Dave","action":"browse"}
{"timestamp":1487271534,"user":"Dave","action":"navigate"}
```

I want to load this data into dictionary similar to what json.load function does

How can I do that ?

with json.load I am getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/lenovo/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Granular.py", line 5, in <module>
    input_data = json.load(open(r"C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\nlp\input.txt",'r'))
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 299, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 342, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 57)
```

Comment: why don't you use json.load if that is the result you are trying to achieve?

Comment: getting error while using json.load

json.load expects data in following format
[{"timestamp":1487271527,"user":"Dave","action":"browse"},
{"timestamp":1487271528,"user":"Dave","action":"navigate"},..]

Comment: ok, you just are missing commas in your input. give me a sec

Answer (score 1):

Each line in your example file is a separate JSON structure. You probably want to make this clear in the extension of your filename, for example you could use `lsjson` to stand for *line separated JSON*.

In this case, you have to read each one in as a string and the unmarshal to a python dict:

```
import json

with open('example.lsjson') as fh:
    data = [json.loads(line) for line in fh.readlines()]
```

You'll end up with a list of dicts

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(data)
[{u'action': u'browse', u'timestamp': 1487271527, u'user': u'Dave'},
 {u'action': u'navigate', u'timestamp': 1487271528, u'user': u'Dave'},
 {u'action': u'browse', u'timestamp': 1487271529, u'user': u'Dave'},
 {u'action': u'view', u'timestamp': 1487271530, u'user': u'Dave'},
 {u'action': u'browse', u'timestamp': 1487271531, u'user': u'Dave'},
 {u'action': u'browse', u'timestamp': 1487271532, u'user': u'Dave'},
 {u'action': u'browse', u'timestamp': 1487271533, u'user': u'Dave'},
 {u'action': u'navigate', u'timestamp': 1487271534, u'user': u'Dave'}]
```

Comment: did not get a chance to get my solution in before TomDotTom did but this is the one I would have headed toward providing :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your file is missing commas and the brackets for it to be read as an array by json.load.
Just load the file as a string first and add the proper punctuation:

```
with open('test.json', 'r') as fp:
    document = fp.read()
document = '[' + document.replace('\n', ',\n') + ']'
```

Then write the result to another file:

```
with open('test2.json', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write(document)
```

And you will be able to open it with json.load:

```
import json

with open('test2.json', 'r') as fp:
    content = json.load(fp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just read the file as a normal text file and the convert each line to a JSON object using the json.loads method and append it to a list.

**EX:**

```
import json
path = "PATH/TO/INPUT_FILE/data.json"

data = []
with open(path, "r") as infile:
    for line in infile.readlines():
        data.append(json.loads(line))

print data
```

**Output:**

```
[{u'action': u'browse', u'timestamp': 1487271527, u'user': u'Dave'}, {u'action': u'navigate', u'timestamp': 1487271528, u'user': u'Dave'}, {u'action': u'browse', u'timestamp': 1487271529, u'user': u'Dave'}, {u'action': u'view', u'timestamp': 1487271530, u'user': u'Dave'}, {u'action': u'browse', u'timestamp': 1487271531, u'user': u'Dave'}, {u'action': u'browse', u'timestamp': 1487271532, u'user': u'Dave'}, {u'action': u'browse', u'timestamp': 1487271533, u'user': u'Dave'}, {u'action': u'navigate', u'timestamp': 1487271534, u'user': u'Dave'}]
```